# Parent div getting smaller before its elements

Tags: html, css

I am making non responsive top search-navigation bar. Here is my code:

```css
body{
  margin:0;
  font-size:14px;
  font-family:arial;
}
.tpnv{
  padding:10px;
  border-bottom:1px solid #aaa;
  background-color:red;
}
.nvblt{

}
.brndr{
  margin-right:50px;
}
.brnd{
  width:150px;
}
.srch{
  font-size:14px;
  outline:none;
}
#srchctgry{
  padding:10px 1px;
  width:100px;
  border:1px solid #aaa;
}
#srchfld{
  padding:10px;
  width:500px;
  border:2px solid black;
}
#srchbtn{
  padding:12px 30px;
  border:none;
  color:white;
  background-color:blue;
  cursor:pointer;
}
#srchbtn:active{
  background-color:darkblue;
}
.nv{
  margin:25px;
  font-size:20px;
  color:black;
}
```

```html
<div class="tpnv">
  <table class="nvblt">
    <tr>
      <td><a href="/mayukh" class="brndr"><img src="md/brnd/mykhmn.png" class="brnd" alt="Mayukh" title="home" draggable="false"></a></td>
      <td>
        <select class="srch" id="srchctgry">
          <option>All</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="srch" id="srchfld" placeholder="What are you looking for?">
      </td>
      <td><button class="srch" id="srchbtn">Search</button></td>
      <td><a href="#" class="nv" title="Cart"><i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i></a></td>
      <td><a href="#" class="nv" title="Account"><i class="fas fa-user"></i></a></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

But the problem is when I resize my browser window to check the design in other ratio monitors, the parent div (".tpnv") gets smaller before the table (".nvblt"). How can I prevent the div from shrinking before its child elements?

Comment: **Do not abuse tables for layout purposes.** We stopped doing that 20 years ago! `table` elements are for displaying **tabular data**, **nothing else!**

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this question uses an invalid approach which it seeks fixes for.

Answer (score 0):

the navbar div gets smaller because the div adapts it's width to 100% of the screen, where you search bar overflows in the div. You can give `width: fit-content;` for the error. So your class definition would look like:

```
.tpnv{
  padding:10px;
  border-bottom:1px solid #aaa;
  background-color:red;
  width: fit-content;
}
```

Although, It's not a good practice to use tables for navbars (as @connexo mentioned). It would be better if you use bootstrap.

To do that, Include the bootstrap CDN in your html and copy the navbar code from [Bootstrap navbar](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/navbar/) and remove the unnecessary elements. It will be more responsive if you do this, Since it's pretty hard to make responsive designs manually and nobody does it now a days unless required.

Here's a better approach using CSS flex boxes (adding this since @connexo requested). Anyways, I'd still recommend using a framework since I find it a better option to do things without "re-inventing the wheels".

NB: There's a chance that this will fail on mobile devices since the contents would be larger than a mobile screen can accommodate. You may need to use CSS media queries to add specific CSS for mobile devices.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

/* NECESSARY CSS BELOW (Un-necessary above^) */

.navbar {
  background: red;
  padding: 10px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.navbar>div{
  padding: 0 5px;
}

.navbar .search {
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
  gap: 5px;
}
.flex-grow-1{
  flex-grow: 1;
}

/* YOUR CSS COPIED */

#srchctgry{
  padding:10px 1px;
  width:100px;
  border:1px solid #aaa;
}
#srchfld{
  padding:10px;
  border:2px solid black;
}
#srchbtn{
  padding:12px 30px;
  border:none;
  color:white;
  background-color:blue;
  cursor:pointer;
}
#srchbtn:active{
  background-color:darkblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
  <div class="logo">
    <a href="/mayukh" class="brndr"><img src="md/brnd/mykhmn.png" class="brnd" alt="Mayukh" title="home" draggable="false"></a>
  </div>
  <div class="search">
    <select class="srch" id="srchctgry">
      <option>All</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" class="srch flex-grow-1" id="srchfld" placeholder="What are you looking for?">
    <button class="srch" id="srchbtn">Search</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please do not try to fix problems within invalid approaches. Instead, either vote to close, or suggest a minimal solution that is **viable**. If you feel like you cannot, or don't want to do that, feel free to make suggestions in the comments. Suggesting Bootstrap for any CSS job is like suggesting jQuery for any Javascript task - it's overkill and in many (honestly *most*) cases totally unnecessary.

Comment: @connexo Thanks for the the recommendation. I've included a better approach in the answer. It would be so king if you could take back the down-vote if it's been added by you. Thanks.

Comment: Your answer still contains a suggested fix for the table approach. I'm kindly asking you to remove that as it encourages OP and future readers to stick with the invalid approach.